# If a UIWebView displays a remote page with a username/password then can the native code tell if/when it has been validated?

Tags: ios

I have a requirement for an app to communicate with a server, this communication is done using a proprietary http based protocol and the app uses NSUrlConnection for this.

However before the app can be used the user must first perform a one-off registration, and the requirement is that this is done by them logging onto a web page which will be downloaded and displayed in a UIWebView. As a UIWebView is used I no longer have access to the HTTP header/body  nor the NSURLConnectionDelgate etc. for this part of things.

My question is, how can the app know if and when the user has successfully logged onto the web site?

Comment: Is there anything that can be done using an NSURLProtocol somehow?

Comment: Did you manage to get authentication from these? I am thinking of just send an OK request to catch in the UIWebViewDelegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to implement some code in the [connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection%3adidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge%3a) method of the **NSURLConnectionDelegateProtocol**. There's more information about how to respond to a challenge [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, but a UIWebView isn't loaded using an NSURLConnection, so no access to use a NSURLConnectionDelegate AFAIK.